# Create a new table in Oracle SQL with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, ddl

Table: sold

```
user        date_sold       item        price
Ram         ‘2018-01-01’    ABDS21      24
Roze        ‘2018-01-02’    ASAS31      100
```

I have to create a new a table based on `Sold` table given above that has a column `sold_already` that is a Boolean, with a value of

- `‘true’` if they sold that item before
- `‘false’` if it’s their first time selling that item.

This is my query but it is not working:

```
CREATE table sold_boughtsign 
    ( user varchar, 
      date_sold date, 
      item varchar, 
      price number, 
      bought_before boolean);

INSERT INTO sold_boughtsign 
  (user, date_sold,item, price) 
SELECT user, date_sold,item, price
FROM sold 
IF(bought_before IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) 
From User INNER JOIN items ON user=item
```

Comment: this is my query but it is not working

Comment: CREATE table sold_boughtsign (
user varchar,
date_sold date,
item varchar,
price number,
bought_before boolean)

INSERT INTO sold_boughtsign (user, date_sold,item, price)
SELECT user, date_sold,item, price FROM sold
       IF(bought_before IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) 
From User INNER JOIN items
ON user=item

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Oracle RDBMS does not support boolean datatype, although I wonder if you are in fact using MySQL which does. So, when you say your query does not work, how does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Query you wrote suggests that there's yet another table, `items`, but we don't know how it looks or what it contains - therefore, I'm using my imagination.

Sample tables & data (note that you can't use `user` as a column name; there's a function in Oracle which returns currently logged user, so I'm prefixing it with a "c_"):

```
SQL> create table items (item varchar2 (20));

Table created.

SQL> create table sold
  2  (
  3     c_user      varchar2 (20),
  4     date_sold   date,
  5     item        varchar2 (20),
  6     price       number
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into items
  2    select 'ABDS21' from dual union
  3    select 'ASAS31' from dual union
  4    select 'XXX'    from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> insert into sold
  2    select 'Ram' , date '2018-01-01', 'ABDS21', 24  from dual union
  3    select 'Roze', date '2018-01-02', 'ASAS31', 100 from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

A new table: as there's no Boolean datatype in SQL, we have to choose how to overcome that limitation. For example, you could use a `NUMBER` datatype and store 0 (for false) and 1 (for true). I chose a `VARCHAR2` datatype and put 'Y' there (as "yes, item was sold") and 'N' (no, it wasn't sold yet). Also, I created a check constraint to make sure that users can't enter anything else into that column.

```
SQL> create table sold_boughtsign
  2  (
  3     c_user          varchar2 (20),
  4     date_sold       date,
  5     item            varchar2 (20),
  6     price           number,
  7     bought_before   varchar2 (1) check (bought_before in ('Y', 'N'))
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Finally, let's populate that table:

```
SQL> insert into sold_boughtsign
  2    (c_user, date_sold, item, price, bought_before)
  3  select s.c_user, s.date_sold, i.item, s.price,
  4    decode(s.date_sold, null, 'N', 'Y') bought_before
  5  from items i left join sold s on s.item = i.item;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from sold_boughtsign;

C_USER               DATE_SOLD  ITEM                      PRICE B
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- -
Ram                  2018-01-01 ABDS21                       24 Y
Roze                 2018-01-02 ASAS31                      100 Y
                                XXX                             N

SQL>
```